# jquery: Callback not received on clicking of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I need to send a request on click of button but callback is not received on firing of click event of the button.
Following is code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#trail").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
        if (counter < 1) {
            $("#searchboxdiv").after('<input type="text" id="searchbox">');
            $("#searchbox").after('<input type="button" id="searchbutton" value="search">');
            counter++;
        }
    });
    $("#searchbutton").click(function () {
        var dataToSend = null;
        $.ajax({
            data: dataToSend,
            url: "FormHandler",
            success: function (result) {},
            beforeSend: function () {
                dataToSend = $("#searchbox").val();
            }
        });
    });
    $("#searchboxdiv").on('click', "#searchbutton", function(){
        var data = null;

    });
});
```

I added the textbox in the dialog box dynamically and on click of button in dialog box, callback is not received

Comment: If I ever write a JS engine it will reject such code with `Exception: ugly indenting`. (I ran your code through http://jspretty.com to tidy it up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options:

- Use event delegation. Bind the click to immediate static parent like this :

  ```
   $("#searchboxdiv").on('click', "#searchbutton", function(){ });
  ```
- Or, bind it to the document.

  ```
   $(document).on('click', "#searchbutton", function(){ });
  ```
- Or, move the existing click after `counter++;`, ie., inside  `$("#trail")`'s click handler.

For more info, see [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Option two worked for me. Thanks for answering, but i could not understand the failure of option one

Comment: @KanishkaGupta is `#searchboxdiv` dynamic or static?

Comment: searchboxdiv is static <div>

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation (*for dynamically added `#searchbutton`*)

```
 $('#searchboxdiv').on('click',"#searchbutton",function(){
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I think i need to understand the concept of event delegation before moving ahead, i will get some knowledge regarding same, will  use your suggestion and mark it as correct if stuff works. Thanks for telling.

Comment: This trick did not worked for me. I have updated the code in the question, i refer this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/) as a reference